# Can't use materialize-select?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

i try to use materialize-select,and it does't work?

```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<label>Materialize Select</label>
```

JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
```

});

Comment: What isn't working? The style or the functionality?

Comment: Style not working

Comment: Do you have the .css loaded in a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="URL">` element?

Comment: Try putting a browser-default class on the select tag `<select class="browser-default">`

Comment: <select class="browser-default">  thanks,now it woks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems,{});
  });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>

 <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
  </div>

      <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: what did you change??

Comment: It was missing the `<script>` tag and the `<link>` tag for js/css of materialize. Also, `options` wasn't declared so I replaced it with `{}`