# Why does my Materialize Select not work, even though I copied the code?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I literally copied the code from [Can't use materialize-select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204352/cant-use-materialize-select) but I think the problem lays somewhere else. I also cannot use datepicker, but components like Dropdown-navbar work, I don't get it.

So the problem with my select is, that it won't even show up and the problem with the datepicker is, that the modal-content, won't show up.

I've got a feeling that I just made a simple mistake somewhere in my setup.

````
<html>

<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"
        media="screen,projection" />

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <label>Materialize Select</label>
    </div>

    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
            var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close this tag :  `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js">`
 and create a new tag script that will contain your script

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
            var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
        });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"
        media="screen,projection" />

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <label>Materialize Select</label>
    </div>

    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
            var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, {});
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```